# How to define a principal divisor on general complex spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, divisors

[I am not a native English speaker, so my sentences may sound strange. ]

I'm studying about complex analytic spaces. For meromorphic functions, I don't know how to define their principal divisors because I don't know the definition of the discrete valuation on analytic space.

Let $X$ be a normal complex analytic space. It seems that a prime divisor $D$ is defined as an irreducible codim 1 closed subspace of $X$. If it were an algebraic variety, we could define the valuation of meromorphic function $f$ on $D$ because its structure ring $\mathcal{O}_D =\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}$ is 1-dimensional regular Noetherian local ring.

On complex analytic space, $\mathcal{O}_D $ :Noetherian local ring is true, but maybe not even UFD. So HOW define these?

Comment: What's your definition of **normal**? Doesn't that imply that $X$ is regular in codimension 1?

Comment: $X$ is normal when every $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is normal ring(integral and integrally closed in its fraction field). $X$ is regular in codim 1 is true. But I thought it doesn't mean every $D$ is always regular.

Comment: I'm also unclear that such $\mathcal{O}_{D,x}$ is 1-dim(in the sense of Krull dimension).

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  I do not fully understand what you are asking.  Do you want an alternative definition of principal divisor that manifestly works for complex analytic spaces (e.g., the pushforward via the projection to $X$ of the pullback from the projective line of the "tautological" principal divisor with respect to the closure of the graph of the meromorphic function in the product of the projective line and $X$)?  Or are you asking how to extend the algebraic approach to also work for complex analytic spaces?

Comment: @map: You are right, $D$ does not need to be regular, but you don't need that. What you need is that $X$ is regular at the generic point of $D$. Also, it is not $\mathscr O_{D,x}$ that should be 1-dimensional, but $\mathscr O_{X,\delta}$ where $\delta$ is the generic point of $D$. The fact that $D$ has codimension 1 should mean that that ring is 1-dimensional.

Comment: @JasonStarr What I want to know is the latter approach. I mainly deal with compact, connected, and normal complex spaces, so I would like to know what can be handled under these conditions.

Comment: @SándorKovács I see, thank you very much!  Does a generic point $x$ of $D$  satisfy following condition? → Some prime elements $f$ defines $D$ around  $x$, i.e. $\mathcal{O}_{D,x} =\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/(f_x)$ (Sorry if I'm not making sense.)

Comment: @map, I believe so. $X$ being normal implies that this ring is integrally closed, the fact that D has codimension 1 implies that it is 1-dimensional, so it is indeed a DVR and in particular its maximal ideal (which is the ideal defining D) is principal.

Comment: @SándorKovács Do you have a reference for dealing with generic points of complex analytic spaces? References I know (eg Grauert's and Remmert's CAS) don't mention them, and I currently have some problem to define them: They seem to be incompatible with the (relatively fine) euclidean topology, and if I consider the analytic Zariski topology, I don't know if the local rings $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ change. See also [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517449/what-are-the-stalks-of-holomorphic-functions-wrt-the-analytic-zariski-topology).